# Can kebab case have upper case letters as first letter?

Tags: naming-conventions, kebab-case

Is there a strict definition for kabab case naming convention? Are uppercase letters allowed in kebab case? Does the following names follow kebab case?

```
Article
Article-Body
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of your examples adhere to the kebab case convention which only concerns how words in an identifier are separated. According to Wikipedia this naming convention is also called *lisp-case*, *COBOL-CASE* or *brochette-case*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Delimiter-separated_words

It's worth noting that basically every programming language support *PascalCase* and *camelCase*, most support *snake_case* but only a few support *kebab-case* (since it clashes with the syntax for subtraction). Another interesting observation about snake case and kebab case is that they trade expression readability for identifier readability. Here are three examples:

```
myFirstVariable - mySecondVariable
my_first_variable - my_second_variable
(- my-first-variable my-second-variable)
```

In the first example the operator "-" stands out more so we see directly that this is a subtraction. In there last two lines there is more "noise" since the underscore character and the dash look somewhat like an operator. In this case the identifiers are easier to read but the expression is harder to read.